# Not able to send the default value in function

Tags: reactjs

I am using onChange in selection but when i click on A(Which is Default value) option its not sending in function but when i click B which is not Default value in row 1 its send the value to function

How can i Capture value when i Click A and Also B option to send that value in function

Code:-

```
 <select id="SelectFocus" value={playdata.ChannelName} tabIndex={-1}
                                            className="btn_primary"  
                                            onChange={(e) => { setPlayer(e.target.value, playdata.idx); setHighlightPlayer(e.target.value, playdata.idx) }}                                      >
                                            {Channelname.map((val, id) => {

                                                return (
                                                    <Fragment key={id}>
                                                        {([...val]).map((val1) => {
                                                            //console.log(val1,index1);
                                                            return <option value={val1} key={val1}>{val1}</option>;
                                                        })}
                                                    </Fragment>
                                                )
                                            })
                                            }

                                        </select>
```

Maybe Onchange is not able to send the default value to function is there any other ways? to send the value when i click

Comment: Why do you have your `<option>` tags wrapped in a `<Fragment/>` ? That seems unnecessary to me

Comment: i don't understand the question properly, assuming you don't want a default selection if the value is `null || undefined` just add `<option hidden value={null}></option>` right after `select`

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because `onChange` only triggers when there is a change in `element`. If the user goes with `default value` then it won't trigger the `onChange` function.

So what you can do is put `default values` in your `player` and `highlightPlayer` state, that way if the user goes with `default value` then it will automatically choose the `default value` when the function is `submitted`.